# Handling multiple GraphQL subscription events in React

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

This has been driving me mad and I can't seem to find anyone else with the same problem, which probably means that I'm missing something fundamental.

I'm using AWS Amplify and have a GraphQL endpoint upon which I'm subscribing to a few events (update, create, delete) in a React project. I have a table bound to my list object that holds my data.

When multiple events come in, my state gets all messed up due to it being asynchronous and my table ends up missing a whole chunk of data. I've tried using useReducer to see if that makes a difference but it doesn't. I feel like I need a way to queue the subscription events and then use them, which makes me wonder if this is not standard practice or I'm missing something fundamental.

This is my reducer.

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
      case "ADD":
         return { ...state, productList: action.payload };
      case "UPDATE":
         //update code
      case "DELETE":
         //delete code
      default:
         return state;
   }
};
```

My initial load and setup within the component

```
   const [state, despatch] = useReducer(reducer, { productList: [] });

   useEffect(() => {
      fetchData()
         .then((result) => {
            despatch({ type: "ADD", payload: result });
         })
         .catch((err) => console.log(err));

      setupSubscriptions();
      return () => unsubscribe();
   }, []);
```

My subscriptions

```
   function setupSubscriptions() {
      subscriptionOnCreateProduct = API.graphql(graphqlOperation(onCreateProduct)).subscribe({
         next: (e) => {
            const product = e.value.data.onCreateProduct;
            despatch({ type: "ADD", payload: product });
         },
      });
...
```

An finally my render

```
return (
...
{state.productList.map((product) => (
  // Display my data
))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my frustration, I posted this in haste.

I needed to setup different action types for the initial load and when a subscription event adds a new item.

My reducer now looks like this...

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
      case "INIT_LOAD":
         return { ...state, productList: action.products };
      case "ADD":
         return { ...state, productList: [...state.productList, action.product] };
      case "UPDATE":

      ...

      default:
         return state;
   }
};
```